# How can JavaScript receive the Timestamp of the DB's last entry?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, timestamp

***Note*** that this is different is because I want Javascript to receive it.

***Even if I have to switch to sockets later, I'd like to know how to do it this method. Although I may switch to a push method later, NOT interested currently***

The reason is I would like to reduce server resources used, due to the fact that my chat currently checks for messages every 500 milliseconds, which is crazy bad; however, it is necessary because some of my users type messages all the time, **BUT** some users only time for example a message every 2 minutes. Therefore I would like to know how to get the timestamp of a DB's last entry to determine if they have sent a message in the last say, 30 seconds, then retrieve messages every 10 seconds. If they've sent one in the past 2 minutes, check every 30 secs, but if they're very active increment the time interval. The point is determine the interval based on the activity. I've already surpassed my CPU once, I would like to try not too. **I may have to switch to sockets, which I have NO experience with whatsoever.**

If I do happen to get the timestamp; what do I do with the timestamp with the time?

> Timestamp - time() = time in milliseconds?

Could I for example set the timestamp as a cookie like so.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

document.cookie...

var getMsg = function(){

 $.ajax {
url: php.php,
...
}

}

if(document.cookie < 30 secs){
var time = 500;
} 

setInterval(time, getMsg)

});
```

php.php:

```
<?php
 ...
 setCookie("timestamp data");
 ...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pooling your server all the time, you can do the opposite - when a message is inserted in your database by your app, you send a message to your clients.

WebSockets is the answer.

There are a few libraries already built that make it easy to use:

- ASP.Net SignalR, if you're using Microsoft stack (used, works and
  it's simple);
- Socket.IO, if you're using NodeJS (also used, works and it's simple);
- Ratchet, for php (never used)
- You can also use Meteor
- Other, depends of what technology you use

Comment: Technically this should be a comment, not an answer. But it's such a good comment that it deserves to be an answer. :-)

Comment: I've tried to insert a comment, but it requires a reputation of 50 and I was 26 at the time. Sorry and thank you

Comment: I am already aware of this, if you read the last partr of my question; however, which is the easiest as far as use and installing?

Comment: I use PHP for my server side.